hola tengo un problema al instalar sql server al completar la descaga me sale este error Unknown error (0xe0000235)
estoy desde una mac m3 estoy virtualizando windows 11 y a la hora de instalar sql server me sale este error
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2022 Setup
The following error has occurred:
Unknown error (0xe0000235)
For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=2209051&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=16.0.1000.6&EvtType=0xF57C3D6F%25400xDC80C325

BUTTONS:
OK
ya trate de subiendo la ram el disco quitanto el antivirus

¿Qué información relevante hay en el log de la instalación?

Comparte con nosotros los archivos Summary.txt y Detail.txt que encontrarás en esta ruta en disco:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Setup Bootstrap\Log
